# Fit in a commnad obj a list of obj and quantity

Tags: grails

I'm new about Grails Framework, I'm using the latest available at the moment 3.3.8.
I have an html table with for each row two input tags like this:

```
<input value="123" name="productId" type="hidden">
<input value="6" name="qty">
```

productId is an id of a domain object called Product, while qty is a number (Long).
I will have multiple rows with different quantities and productId in my table and a button to submit a form that inside has this table.
I'd like to have a command object that is filled once I hit the submit button. Basically it should have a list of map object each one with a Product and a quantity,m but I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you only fill in quantities, you can do something like this:

gsp:

```
<g:each in="${productList}" var="product">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Product ${product.id}:</label>
            <input value="" name="qty_${product.id}">
        </td>
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

controller:

```
params.findAll{it.key.startsWith("qty_")}.each{ key, value->        
    def productId = key.split("_")[1].toLong()
    def qty = value.toLong()
    //do something
}
```